# encrypted password file which expires after 24 hours

Tags: python, selenium, encryption, passwords

I am using python scripts to login to various sites to download sensitive data. Password credentials are passed to the scripts when they are run. Is it possible to have the password read from an encrypted file? Further, can that encrypted password file 'expire' after say 24 hours?

- USE Case 1: Deploy the script to production without hard coding the password in a batch file (windows/azure/python/SQL Server) In this case the encrypted password file is set to never expire.
- USE Case: I give an existing script to developer who must modify it against the production site (in this case the production site is the site where I download the sensitive data). I can NOT change my password at the target site. Assume the developer will not need to login to the site to do the work; when the developer runs python-selenium script, it logs in using the encrypted password file the developer will see enough to identify where it breaks then make the modifications.

Comment: You could encrypt it with a key that was removed, making decryption impossible.  But if the users need to be able to decrypt within the 24 hour window, and you can never rotate the password, what's the point?  I would probably have a Dev password in a few environment so I didn't have to give out a prod password I thought was sensitive and I couldn't easily rotate, make sure prod was consistent with dev, and have the humans debug in dev.

Comment: A dev version of the site I log into to get the files is not possible. Nor can I change the password.  My hope is the decryption happens within the python script and is not visible to the developer. Is this an unreasonable expectation? Running the script gets you into the site, but there is no way to see or steal the password. Is it reasonable?

Comment: Not really reasonable, no.  If the script can /decrypt/derive/somehow-determine the password and someone other than you has the script, then they, by definition, also have the password.  This is an issue you need to solve server side, not client side.

Comment: Thank you Luke, this makes sense now that I write it out.

Comment: This is a long shot, but if you had a place to run the script but not access for the dev, they might be able to work on the script without being able to pull the password.  For example, put the password in aws ssm and have the script run in an ec2 instance on a got push.  The dev could still write the script to expose the password, but at least you'd know it.

Comment: Hey Dan, Sadly I can't follow. I'm stuck in a Windows client server paradigm. I like what your getting at though. Some report showing me that the developer 'peeked' as opposed to the script encrypting to do it's job. Seems helpful.